# Workbox is not working and nothing show up in cache

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I have added service worker and workbox as following
In template file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker
                .register('sw.js')
                .then(function(registration) {
                    console.log('Service Worker registration successful with scope: ',
                        registration.scope);
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log('Service Worker registration failed: ', err);
                });
        }
    })();
</script>
```

And in sw.js, I have

```
importScripts('workbox-sw.prod.v2.1.2.js');

const workboxSW = new WorkboxSW();
if (workboxSW) {
    console.log('Yay! workboxSW is loaded');
    const staleWhileRevalidateStrategy = workboxSW.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate();
    workboxSW.router.registerRoute('/*\.css/', staleWhileRevalidateStrategy);
} else {
    console.log('Boo! workboxSW didn\'t load');
}
```

I can see in the console log that "Service Worker registration successful" and "Yay! workboxSW is loaded". But I don't see anything under cache storage (Application -> Cache Storage). How can I update it so that I can see cache content by the service worker?

Comment: I don't know if you still need help on this given how old the question is but what you're essentially doing is caching only during runtime. It will show up in "Cache Storage" after you close your browser and service-worker has chance to finally kick in which now goes through your "route". Perhaps, you might be looking for "workbox precache" https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching ?